# USB detection issue

Tags: usb

I am facing some USB issue in Ubuntu 16.04, I have one hls streaming server for live TV broadcasting. I am using an EasyCAP capture device.

My problem is when I am rebooting my device the USB EasyCAP device is not detecting properly.

How can I fix this issue?